# postgresql with Node js Sequalize One-To-One allows multiple instances of model 1 to be related to the same instance of model 2

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I am trying to create different model association using node js and sequalize, but I am having problems creating a one-to-one association.

The documentation says to use .hasOne() and .belongsTo() to create a One-To-One. From the sequalize documentation:

```
Foo.hasOne(Bar);
Bar.belongsTo(Foo);
```

results in the following sql statement:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "foos" (
  /* ... */
);
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "bars" (
  /* ... */
  "fooId" INTEGER REFERENCES "foos" ("id") ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE
  /* ... */
);
```

Alright now isn't a One-To-One association should have a constraint to prevent multiple 'Bars' from referring to the same 'Foo'? because I can't see such a constraint in the resulting sql, and I have tried the code and yes I can have multiple 'Bars' pointing to one 'Foo' which makes it a One-To-Many isn't it?

Also from the documentation a One-To-Many association with the following code:

```
Team.hasMany(Player);
Player.belongsTo(Team);
```

results in the following sql statement:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "Teams" (
  /* ... */
);
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "Players" (
  /* ... */
  "TeamId" INTEGER REFERENCES "Teams" ("id") ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  /* ... */
);
```

which is identical to the One-To-One resulting sql statement. Am I missing something. Someone help please.

I am expecting the 'fooId' column to have a unique restraint to prevent multiple "bars" from relating to a single "foo"

Comment: Did you try only using `Foo.hasOne(Bar);` without belongsTo?

Comment: Yes, the same result. I am really going crazy at this point.

Comment: what is your expect sql query for one-to-one ?

Comment: CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "foos" (
  /* ... */
);
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "bars" (
  /* ... */
  "fooId" INTEGER UNIQUE REFERENCES "foos" ("id")  ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE
  /* ... */
);

Comment: I am expecting a unique constraint on the fooId column to make sure only one bar can be related to one foo, but the resulting query is identical to one-to-many not one-to-one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is odd that `Foo.hasOne(Bar)` is not enough to create any constraints to stop multiple `Bar` objects from being associated with the same `Foo` object, at least in `version 6 of sequelize`.  However, there is a difference in the instance methods on a `Foo` object where `Foo.hasOne(Bar)` versus `Foo.hasMany(Bar)` (see [the docs for associations](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/assocs.html#special-methods-mixins-added-to-instances)).  Specifically, you'll have:

> Foo.hasOne(Bar)
>
> > fooInstance.getBar()
> > fooInstance.setBar()
> > fooInstance.createBar()

versus

> Foo.hasMany(Bar)
>
> > fooInstance.getBars()
> > fooInstance.countBars()
> > fooInstance.hasBar()
> > fooInstance.hasBars()
> > fooInstance.setBars()
> > fooInstance.addBar()
> > fooInstance.addBars()
> > fooInstance.removeBar()
> > fooInstance.removeBars()
> > fooInstance.createBar()

That being said, unique constraints can be added to the model definitions.  For example,

```
let Parent = sequelize.define('parent', {
        id: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            allowNull: false,
            autoIncrement: true,
            primaryKey: true
        },
        name: DataTypes.STRING
    },
    {
        tableName: 'parents',
        timestamps: false
    })

let Child = sequelize.define('child', {
        id: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            allowNull: false,
            autoIncrement: true,
            primaryKey: true
        },
        name: DataTypes.STRING,
        parentId: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            references: {
                model: Parent,
                key: 'id'
            },
            unique: true
        }
    },
    {
        tableName: 'children',
        timestamps: false
    })

Parent.hasOne(Child, {
    foreignKey: 'parentId',
    sourceKey: 'id'
})
Child.belongsTo(Parent, {
    foreignKey: 'parentId',
    targetKey: 'id'
})
```

The import part of the above snipped is the line that reads:

> unique: true

This will result in:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "children" ("id"   SERIAL , "name" VARCHAR(255), "parentId" INTEGER UNIQUE REFERENCES "parents" ("id") ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE, PRIMARY KEY ("id"));
```

Comment: Yeah exactly it is very weird why it is not supported given it is v6. I really was questioning my whole programming and sql knowledge at that point. Thanks for the solution.